# G Suite - incomplete application manifest

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

Many years ago, I published my web app [www.Photopea.com](https://www.Photopea.com) at

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard

[image]

It was supposed to add an icon somewhere into Chrome, which would redirect to Photopea.com (so basically just a bigger bookmark).

It is listed twice, since the first listing was supposed to be for Chrome WebStore, and the second one for G Suite (which I never used in my life and I don't know how it works).

Many of my users report, that they try to add Photopea into their G Suite doman, and they see "Information provided in application manifest is not complete". Which of these two items should I edit, and how should the new manifest look like?

Can I test "adding Photopea to G Suite domain" myself somehow (not sure what it means)? To be able to check, if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Your G Suite Marketplace app is [here](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/photopea/463342976776) and the Chrome Web Store extension is [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/photopea/fmophgdjdipcbfjiopifpngdjmemonko).

Regarding the GSM app, you can install it for yourself and if you are the admin of a domain, you can install it for all users in the domain.

Note that the Drive extension is going to be [migrated](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/cws-migration) to the G Suite Marketplace. In your case both app use the same cloud project, so after the migration there will be a single listing in GSM (the current one).

Comment: Hi, when I click on Install in GSM myself, I see a new window with a following content: https://i.imgur.com/mHYlWEC.png . Is it a problem with the manifest? How should the right manifest look like and where should I upload it?

Comment: Your extension was missing the scopes. I've added the default ones and was able to install your app. If your extension needs other scopes please add them in the GSM SDK in the Cloud Console.

Comment: Thanks! But how could I change the scope myself? Is it really necessary to use both Cloud Console and Chrome Webstore Dashboard to manage G Suite extension? And what is the difference between clicking Install in GSM, and between Google Drive - Settings - Manage Apps - Connect more apps?

Comment: It was a bug, it wasn't supposed to fail.

Comment: Regarding the difference between CWS and GSM today it's complicated. There some things that you have to update in CWS and others in GSM. The install story is also complicated. The good news is that we are migrating all G Suite extensions to GSM and we will integrate the GSM widget in Drive so the experience for developers and users will be better.

Comment: There are again many users, who report to me, that my app does not work in G suite. Could you install Photopea in G Suite and tell me, what the problem is? I don't have access to G Suite and I don't know anyone else who could help me :(